# Easy way to mark a question as duplicate and stopping reputation gain on such question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, reputation, badges

*Some background*

Recently I came across a question on SO which was very simple. Looking at the question my impression was that the question would be from a newbie in programming. But when I looked at the user profile I was surprised to see that user has ~6k reputation, ~50 gold badges, ~150 silver and ~250 bronze badges. When I took a closer look at the user's profile I realized that this is due to large number of questions, many of which were popular, asked by that user (total 1000+ questions in 2000+ days of activity; out of these 600+ with 0 votes, 100+ with -ve votes and 300+ with +ve votes; on the other hand only 10 answers out of which 2 answers had 1 vote and 8 answers had 0 votes).

When I searched on Meta I found few discussions regarding this:

[Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271985/laziness-is-rewarded-big-time-by-the-reputation-system)

[Massive rep earned from just asking a popular question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306137/massive-rep-earned-from-just-asking-a-popular-question)

[What to do with the question which just asked to attract votes and to gain reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311263/what-to-do-with-the-question-which-just-asked-to-attract-votes-and-to-gain-reput)

I could see that people are discussing about the reputation and, more importantly, privileges earned by asking simple/duplicate questions. But there doesn't seem to be any way to stop this, as far as I could understand it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

*Current System:*

When I try to `Ask Question` I get to see `Similar Questions` section which highlights the questions that are similar to what I'm asking and I could possible get answers there. So I'm supposed to check those questions and not ask my question if its going to be a duplicate. But if I am lazy or just want to gain reputation, by asking simple question that could become popular, I will not bother to look at those similar questions. If I continue and ask my question anyway, I would probably get a few upvotes and high view count giving me some badges.

Now if someone else takes a look at my question he doesn't get to see the `Similar Questions` section. There is a `Related` section but its not that prominent. So the person viewing my question won't easily know that its a duplicate. Also `Flag` is not an intuitive way to mark a question as duplicate.

*Suggestion / Feature Request*

1. When someone is answering a question, `Similar Questions`/`Related` (if both are same) section should be shown **prominently** alongside. So that the person who is answering the question can at least check / take a quick look if the question asker has been lazy / trying to gain reputation by asking simple / popular question.
2. `Mark as duplicate` should be placed alongside `Flag` option to make it quickly accessible.
3. If a question is marked as duplicate any reputation gained from that question should be ignored. If the user has gained 20 reputation due to upvotes, it should be reverted. Even if the question gets 1000+ views it should not result in any badges. Etc. (That reminds me: on one of the links above someone made a comment that answers are rewarded more than questions. But when it comes to view count, the reward goes to asker. The answerer gets reward only when someone upvotes his answer, not when people view his answer)

**EDIT**

Sorry for not being clear earlier. I didn't mean to reset the reputation gained for answers. My suggestion is to reset the reputation only for the question. Its the responsibility of asker to do the homework before asking the question. If he has not done it, he should not get rewarded. The answerers are putting their efforts in good faith and hence should be rewarded and in turn their earned reputation should remain as is.

Comment: This is assuming duplicates are always obvious, and answerers have perfect knowledge of what duplicates exist. That's not always the case, and sometimes duplicates are marked years after the question and answers have been posted. What should happen to the reputation earned for answers written in good faith?

Comment: _"~50 gold badges"_? Wut?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Regarding your point #1. There is no such assumption that duplicates are obvious or answerers have knowledge of what duplicates exist. In fact its the opposite. My point is that currently its not very obvious for answerers to know if current question is a possible duplicate of any existing one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Regarding your point #2. Sorry for not being clear. I didn't mean to reset the reputation gained for answers. My suggestion is to reset the reputation only for the question. Its the responsibility of asker to do the homework before asking the question. If he has not done it, he should not get rewarded. The answers are putting their efforts in good faith and hence should be rewarded and in turn their earned reputation should remain as is.

Comment: @VivekAthalye: In many of these 'duplicates should not be asked' proposals it is the answerers that are seen as the 'enablers', which is why I'm asking about how this will affect them.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes. That's *NOT* a typo. And btw my reaction was "WHAT THE ****(HELL)", specifically after reading the question asked by this user

Comment: This does treat duplicates as being without value altogether. Duplicates *do* have value; they act as waypoints to the canonical, feeding search engines with alternative spellings of the same problem. Not everyone is wired to think about problems the same way. And what if the question is asked *way better* than the original, existing posts? Should an asker that *did their research*, asked a good question with a MCVE, be punished for having stumbled upon an obscure duplicate?

Comment: Anything that helps in making it easier to find and mark questions as duplicates have my support. But touching reputation due to being a duplicate, nah, let's not do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree to your point that duplicates do have value and I did not mean to treat duplicates without any value altogether. If an obscure duplicate could be found by an answerer then most likely asker could also have found it too if he had done some research. Typically what I have observed is that when asker has done his part of research, he himself declares that he has looked at other `similar questions` and provides the links to those questions too. But I agree that there still is a small possibility that such asker has missed a possible duplicate of his question.

Comment: @rene Its not just the reputation but also the privileges that comes along with high reputation. That's the concern I could sense, even in other discussions I read (links in my post above)

Comment: Why is that a concern? You could live with the reputation as long as it doesn't come with a privilege? I really think only points 1 and 2 in your proposal are worth looking at. Point 3 discourages new answers which is a bad thing. The outcome will be: No one answers a question because they are not sure if it is worth it, now or in the future. Once it gets close voted as a dupe the close voters become the target of disgruntled askers and answerers and that might even escalate for gold dupe hammers. The end-result will be: Lots of duplicate questions remain both open **and** unanswered.

Comment: @rene sorry for the confusion about reputation of answerers. I had clarified it in my response to Martijn Pieters but now I've added it in the original post itself.

Comment: @rene Isn't it a concern that a user gets extra privileges due to the high reputation that he has earned because of simple / duplicate / popular questions and not because of his technical ability.

Comment: No, I don't think that is a concern. The question that is asked and answered is judged on their merits by the voters. If you feel that the voters are spending their votes wrong, for example by upvoting duplicate Q/A's instead of down voting, you should address that. Now you blame those that provide their knowledge. The voters are responsible for the reputation. And as we ask the community to vote on the merits of the post I don't see how an OP can be part of the problem. The lack of down voters is the problem. Once that is solved so is your high rep/privilege issue.

Comment: @VivekAthalye: Again, that assumes more skill from the answerer, and that they actually remembered to look for answers that provide the same solution. From personal experience I know that that is not always the case (I've answered posts that I assumed where a new issue, and where my own research did not turn up a suitable dupe, often because the keywords for the topic are crowded with unrelated issues).  I also find dupes because I happen to have personal experience in the issue and know what documentation link to search for, but you can't expect the question asker to have ever found that.

Comment: @rene `The lack of down voters is the problem` Yes I agree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's an interesting thread. Will need some time to read it fully :) ... That question is related to point #3 but I don't think it has anything related to point #1 and #2 mentioned in my question above. Right?

Comment: @VivekAthalye Unfortunately, a lot of people get a lot of rep by asking and answering duplicates. With that much incentive in the system, no one will ever tackle the problem of duplicates. I've seen extremely high-rep users answering obvious duplicates. When called out, they say "it's easier to answer than find the duplicate", even though the duplicate is sitting in the top spot in the Related answers list. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339402/215552.